# How to know webview isDrawing on Canvas in Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

First, my app is a hybrid app, I can know webview event and action via Cordova Plugin to native.In WebView, we have enable Swipe to Next/Previous page with GestureDetector.

The problem is when I draw a straight line on webview,it swipe to Next Page. I don't want to swipe to get next page.So, I need to disable swipe during webview `isDrawing()` on canvas or webview `isZoomed()`.

This is my CustomWebView,

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView;



public class CustomWebView extends SystemWebView {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;



    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /*
     * @see android.webkit.WebView#onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
    }

    /*
     * @see android.webkit.WebView#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev) || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public void setGestureDetector(GestureDetector gestureDetector) {
        this.gestureDetector = gestureDetector;
    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean isZoomed () {
        boolean result = false;

        int contentHeight = getContentHeight();
        int viewHeight = getHeight();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 ) {
            float scale = getScale();
            int temp = (int)(((float)viewHeight / (float)contentHeight) * 100);

            if (temp < (int)(scale * 100)) {
                result = true;
            }
        } else {
            float scale = getScale();
            int temp = (int)(((float)viewHeight / (float)contentHeight) * 100);

            if (temp < (int)(scale * 100)) {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is my GestureDetector,

```
private class CustomeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {



        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

            if(e1 == null || e2 == null) return false;
            if(e1.getPointerCount() > 1 || e2.getPointerCount() > 1) return false;
            else {
                try { // right to left swipe .. go to next page
                    if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > 250 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 800) {

                                slideToLeft();

                                MoveNext();

                        }

                        return true;
                    } //left to right swipe .. go to prev page
                    else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > 250 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 800) {

                                slideToRight();

                                MovePrevious();


                        return true;
                    } 
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the canvas an android canvas or html canvas?

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer, it is a html canvas

Answer (score 0):

You can [listen to touch events on the html canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#Setting_up_the_event_handlers) and inform the `GestureDetector` to "pause".

In order to do that you'll need to open up [a javascript interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) on the `WebView`, something like:

```
public class CustomWebView extends SystemWebView {
    private CustomeGestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public CustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
    }

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
    }

    ...

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onCanvasTouchStart() {
        this.gestureDetector.pause();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onCanvasTouchEnd() {
        this.gestureDetector.resume();
    }
}

private class CustomeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private AtomicBoolean paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void pause() {
        this.paused.set(true);
    }

    public void resume() {
        this.paused.set(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (this.paused.get()) {
            return;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Then in the html/javascript part:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("CANVAS_ID");
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function() { Android.onCanvasTouchStart(); });
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function() { Android.onCanvasTouchEnd(); });
```

I haven't tested any of this, but the general idea should work.

Comment: i will test it and let you know it is work or not,Thanks for your helps.

Comment: i cannot get onTouchEvent() in CustomWebView, bcz you are directly set CustomGestureDetector in CustomWebView.CustomGestureDetector has no onTouchEvent in it.

Comment: `CustomWebView.gestureDetector` wasn't an instance of `CustomGestureDetector`?

Comment: I mean if I use CustomeGestureDetector directly in CustomWebView, i cannot @Override onTouchEvent in CustomWebView.Can I know how to get onTouchEvent,if i use CustomGestureDetector in CustomWebView .Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it, so why do you have `CustomeGestureDetector` if you're not using it?